# IntelliJ code completion like Xcode & Eclipse

Tags: xcode, eclipse, intellij-idea, intellisense

How do I get the code completion in IntelliJ to act like Xcode/Eclipse?

This meaning, typing a method that takes parameters, and when you select the method from the auto-complete list:

```
intToString(int val);
```

In Eclipse, you'll get:

```
intToString( (val-placeholder) );
```

and similar in Xcode.

However, in IntelliJ, all you get is:

```
intToString();
```

How do you get placeholders for parameters in IntelliJ?

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but you can place your caret between the braces and press ctrl+p. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_assistance.html -> Popup parameter info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA. Similar functionality is already implemented in AppCode, so it's possible that it will be ported to IntelliJ IDEA in a future release.

Comment: So how does one get multi-parameter auto complete (SmartComplete) in IDEA 12?
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/09/super-method-completion/

Comment: The multi-parameter auto-complete works only in specific contexts (such as super method calls and delegation), when we know that you're going to be forwarding a bunch of parameters from your current method to the method you're calling. This hasn't changed in IntelliJ IDEA 12 compared to previous versions.

Comment: Here is the related feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5496.